# Who holds copyright in a pastor's sermon?

Tags: united-states, copyright

When a pastor preaches a sermon in a church incorporated as a 501(c)(3) organization, who holds the copyright? The pastor or the church?

Comment: is the pastor an employee or a pass-the-hat preacher?

Comment: @TigerGuy an employee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether he is an employee of the church hired to write and deliver sermons, or not. The building-owner does not gain ownership of a work by letting a person use their venue, unless that is part of a contract ("You can use our church, but you must transfer copyright to us"). If you are asking whether a 501(c)(3) organization can own property, yes it can.